# how to crop the transparent small pieces around the pictures by photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I want to crop just the image not transparent around of that , but these pieces are too small , By which tools you crop carefully instead of using hand cropping ?

I added a picture to show my problem[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `Image > Trim` and choose **transparent pixels** from the pop up.

Sometimes that may leave pixels of a low opacity however. In those cases you can ...

**A)** make a selection and choose `Image > Crop`
**B)** Use `Image > Canvas Size` and set the size you want and where you want the cropping to occur. You'll get a warning that the new canvas is smaller then the document and cropping will occur. Simply click `OK`.